# How can i mark one Jmeter sample as STOP status

Tags: jmeter

> How can i mark one **Jmeter** sample as 
>   STOP

status like we used to do in

> Load Runner ?

Comment: what exactly is this expected to do ? thx

Comment: I need to discard on one HTTP sample result(one iteration) status means do not want to count iteration of the sample as pass or fail. Jmeter should not consider that sample iteration results(response time etc.) for the report.

Comment: You mean you want to ignore it in report ? what is the use case ?

Comment: Are you trying to find something like lr_exit , if yes what mode ? http://eyeontesting.com/questions/7042/in-loadrunner-how-do-the-make-the-vuser-exit-the-i.html

Comment: No..just want to ignore that iteration for the report

Answer (score 0):

In JMeter you cannot ignore an iteration for a report the way it is done in LR.

But you can filter it from [Web Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) using :

> jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=^(Search|Order)(-success|-failure)?$